# Passing an arrow function to a component that uses hooks causes useEffect to fire again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**How to pass an arrow function as a prop to a component that uses hooks without causing useEffect to fire when it shouldn't?**

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-haze-3z90r)

```
function Apple(props) {
  const { text, cb } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    pretendFetch().then(result => cb(result));
    // eslint-plugin-react-hooks dictates that `cb` should be within the dependencies array
  }, [cb]);
  return <div>{text}</div>;
}
```

When the component is passed an arrow function as `cb` it will fire the useEffect on every render.  Ideally it should just use the callback once, but I cannot just pass `[]` as the dependency array without eslint-plugin-react-hooks issuing a warning.  I've read that useRef can be used to wrap the callback but that seems like an unsatisfying bandaid to this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the callback function is recreated on each render and therefore triggers the update in `useEffect`. You can change this behaviour by using the `useCallback` hook to wrap the callback function in the overlying component like I did in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wing-9sf3u)

Comment: Though this works in the example I put forth, my problem is that it is unsafe to pass an arrow function to the component that uses the hook.  If I want to expose that component as a public component on NPM for example, it would cause an issue for anyone who passes an arrow function to that component.

Comment: @Jordan You can still use the same approach but you'd need to wrap the component in another that does the memoizing. Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shape-irccp

Comment: @Linschlager, unfortunately this new approach just gets around the linter but still exposes the program to the problem that the linter is trying to save us from::
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wiles-9h26o

Comment: I submitted an issue with that explained: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18079

Answer (score 1):

I checked [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880) today, having the same problem with you, so I just removed the cb from the useEffect array - in order to trigger it only on mount - and disabled the eslint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to disable the rule, because the rule catches all sorts of hidden gotchas when using hooks.

Comment: There is this note in the react docs which is not absolutely clear, but suggests using an empty array if you want to use it as a componentDidMount: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
If you want to be absolutely clear of warnings either add a condition inside your useEffect or convert it to a class component and use componentDidMount instead. Hope this helps

Comment: You can disable it on a per-line basis using a `//eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment on the same line, you don't need to disable it completely